# How can I add space around tokens without it adding up?

Tags: spacing

I would like to add some padding `\,` around certain tokens, for example probability density functions. Naively, I could use

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\RoundBrackets}[1]{(}{)}{#1}
\newcommand{\p}[1]{\,p\RoundBrackets{#1}\,}
```

However, if two of these tokens follow each other, this inserts two half spaces while I would like to see only one between them. How can I do this?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Why would you add such padding? And why `\left` and `\right`? Can you please show a couple of examples where you deem the space necessary?

Comment: You also might look up \DeclareMathOperator in the amsmath manual.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks! I like the letter p to be italic because it's similar to a variable in my case. I'm actually using `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` for the brackets and updated my question to show that.

Comment: @egreg I'd like `p(x)p(y)` to render as `p(x)\,p(y)` but not `p(x)\,\,p(y)`. I'm not sure what other examples would be useful to demonstrate this but please let me know. I included a screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see no problem in `p(x)p(y)`.

However, what you want can be achieved by turning the *p* into an operator:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\p}{\mathnormal{p}}

\begin{document}

$p(x)p(y)$

$\p(x)\p(y)$

\end{document}
```

[image]